# Python Django Unable To Import Module Within Module

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, import

Not entirely sure how to ask this, I tried searching but couldn't find an answer possibly due to how I phrased it.

Lets say I have:

> myapp/myapp/script1.py
>
> myapp/myapp/main/
>
> myapp/myapp/main/app.py
>
> myapp/myapp/main/util/script2.py

script2.py imports with the following:

```
import myapp.script1
```

I can run script2.py perfectly fine from the console. However when I try to import script2.py into my app.py using:

```
import main.util.script2.py
```

I get an error saying:

> Exception Type:    ImportError
>
> Exception Value:   No module named cb2

cb2 is a dependency in script1.py. However running from script2.py on its own in the console it imports the cb2 with no issue. I've tried import cb2 on its own directly but still get the same issue. cb2 is listed in dependencies in my Config file. Is this a pathing issue that I have overlooked? I'm still pretty new to Django/Python. Sorry if my question is not explained very well I can provide more information if that would help.

Comment: Is cb2 is listed in your pip freeze?

Comment: Can you list your imports in `script1.py`, `script2.py` and `app.py` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to move the import statement from the beginning into the concrete function where you actually need the import module, that's a way to avoid import each other.